# Am having problems using cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, cx-freeze

First of all, the technical stuff:
Python : 3.3
cx_freeze : 4.3.2
I have looked through several setups, but accomplished nothing. So far I only get a very quickly closing Python Command Line, and *sigh*, no exe.
The setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [
        Executable("Swiss Rounds.py", appendScriptToExe=True, appendScriptToLibrary=False)
]

buildOptions = dict(
        create_shared_zip = False)

setup(
        name = "hello",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "the typical 'Hello, world!' script",
        options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
        executables = executables)
```

Thank you people!

Comment: What do you mean by "a very quickly closing video"? Which platform are you running this on? What command are you trying to run this script with? What is the output?

Comment: Quite sorry, should have written Python Command Line instead. Was thinking of finding a video

Comment: You still haven't told us the exact steps you are using to run the script.

Comment: Run the exe from a command prompt to see what's happening when it runs - if you double click on it, then Windows closes the command line as soon as the program exits.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot the base for your executable, so cx freeze doesn't know how to make the exe. This is how I structure my setup.py file. This setup will put the exe in a different folder if it is 32 bit.

```
import os, sys, platform
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

targetDir = "./build/"
build_exe_options = {
     "icon": "/assets/images/icon.ico",
     "build_exe": "/build/",
     "packages": [], 
     "includes": ["re", "os", "atexit"],
     "include_files": ["/assets/"],
     "excludes": ["tkinter", "ttk", "socket", "doctest", "pdb", "unittest", "difflib", 
                  "_bz2", "_hashlib", "_lzma", "_socket"],
     "optimize": True,
     "compressed": True,
    }

is32bit = platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit'
if is32bit:
    targetDir = "./buildX86/"
    build_exe_options["build_exe"] = targetDir
# end

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
# end

setup(  name = "MyProgram",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My program example",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [ Executable("/myprogram.py", 
                                   targetName="MyProgram.exe",
                                   targetDir=targetDir,
                                   base=base) ]
      )
```

Run:

```
python setup.py build
```

Comment: If you leave the base out, the default is the `Console` base. Which might give you the 'quickly closing command line' the questioner sees.